# i used cloudformation to create wordpress blog but domain not showing properly

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-route53

I used cloudformation to create wordpress blog and then bought a domain from godaddy website and forwarded it to the domain name provided by cloudformation.

-->godaddy domain: yetanotherdeveloper.in

-->cloudformation domain: "ec2-35-154-134-194.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress/"

Problem 1: when i search godaddy domain in the URL, i get to the site but then only cloudformation domain is shown in the URL.I want the godaddy domain to be there. When i open a post, before the slash in the URL, cloudformation domain is shown.(eg. ec2-35-154-134-194.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress/index.php**/2017/09/27/hello-world/**) .I want godaddy domain to be there for ease of access for others.

Problem 2: Cloudformation uses a public IP which could be dangerous in future in case the server gets down etc. So, i want to change the IP to elastic IP too.

Thank you!

Comment: It works fine when I type that domain in. I suspect a little patience did the trick.

Comment: How do i change the permalink to show new posts like        yetanotherdeveloper.in//2017/09/27/hello-world/ instead of like   ec2-35-154-134-194.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress/index.php/2017/09/27/hello-world/  and yes it works fine because i masked the cloudformation domain with godaddy domain, and still the posts don't show the way explained above. I think instead of masking the domain from godaddy, there is another way possible which i am missing

Comment: GoDaddy's "domain masking" is a horrible system and you should not use it. You'll want to set up proper DNS records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Wordpress is configured incorrectly. Go into the admin panel, settings, general, and check that your domain name "yetanotherdeveloper.in" is in there. I suspect you have the ec2 URL in there.

CloudFormation is irrelevent in this context.

You've installed Wordpress to a subdirectory - why have you done that? Everything is simpler when it's on the domain root.

I also notice that while your public IP address is 35.154.134.194 your A record is 50.63.202.27. That suggests you've done something weird with GoDaddy, some kind of forwarding.

My suggestions are:

- Move Wordpress to the root of the domain
- Use Route53 as your DNS provider - it's simpler when you keep everything within AWS. You can actually use GoDaddy / CloudFlare free DNS if you understand what you're doing
- Set your A record to point directly at your IP address.

Comment: from where do i get to know what A record is? and yes i did forwarding and masking

Comment: Stop using non-standard features such as forwarding and masking. Use simple Godaddy DNS, put your instance IP address in as the A record. If you want to do anything else you'll have to ask GoDaddy support or hire a consultant to help you.

Comment: An A record is a DNS record that tells the internet what your server IP is. For a website you typically set the A record to your server IP and a CNAME record (alias record) to your website name. eg for a domain example.com you may have an A record called example.com with the value 1.2.3.4 and a CNAME record called www with the value example.com . I think you really need to do a lot of study / reading before you can progress with what you're doing, DNS is basic and fundamental to the internet. Try a training provider like Linux Academy or pluralsight

Comment: You're welcome. If you're happy with my answer please accept it.